# How does the listen method of a stream show data that has been added through a sink AFTER the listen method was called?

Tags: dart, stream

I'm studying the concept and practical uses of streams (very basic level though) and I found that the code below adds data through a sink AFTER the listen method is called. So is the function passed to listen as an argument repeating itself on and on until our program is over?

I've tried pausing the program for a few seconds between each sink.add call but the console printed the entire data at once... I'm still trying to understand how the whole concept works.

```
void main() {

  //
  // Initialize a "Single-Subscription" Stream controller
  //

  final StreamController ctrl = StreamController();

  //
  // Initialize a single listener which simply prints the data
  // as soon as it receives it
  //

  final StreamSubscription subscription = ctrl.stream.listen((data) => print('$data'));

  //
  // We here add the data that will flow inside the stream
  //

  ctrl.sink.add('my name');
  ctrl.sink.add(1234);
  ctrl.sink.add({'a': 'element A', 'b': 'element B'});
  ctrl.sink.add(123.45);

  //
  // We release the StreamController
  //
  ctrl.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function passed to `listen` is a [*callback*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) that the `Stream` invokes whenever data is added to the `Stream` (or until the subscription to the stream is canceled).

This is explained in the [`Stream.listen` documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-async/Stream/listen.html):

> On each data event from this stream, the subscriber's `onData` handler is called.
>
> ...
>
> While a subscription is paused, or when it has been canceled, the subscription doesn't receive events and none of the event handler functions are called.